# netplan parents inteface of vlan has dhcp. i want to disable

Tags: dhcp, vlan

i use netplan to assign ip address with vlan on my ubuntu 22.02.

i disabled dhcp for enp2s0 which is parent of my vlan.20.

But It has dhcp random ip addresse. I want to disable. how to do this?

```
$ cat /etc/netplan/02-netcfg.yaml
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: NetworkManager
  ethernets:
    enp2s0:
      dhcp4: no //disable 
  vlans:
    vlan.20:
      id: 20
      link: enp2s0
      addresses: ["192.168.20.190/24"]
```

```
root@dir3:/etc/netplan# ip -4 a
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
3: enp2s0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state UP group default qlen 1000
    inet 169.254.73.97/16 brd 169.254.255.255 scope link noprefixroute enp2s0 //it has ip!!
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
17: vlan.20@enp2s0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP group default qlen 1000
    inet 192.168.20.190/24 brd 192.168.20.255 scope global noprefixroute vlan.20
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

enp2s0 interface has `169.254.73.97/16` ip address.
how to remove that ip address?